# AngularDart touch and move

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am using AngularDart for creating scrollable card:

```
<acx-scoreboard scrollable>
    <acx-scorecard
            *ngFor="let game of games"><carouselFixture [stream]="gane.stream" *ngIf="game.viewModelType == 'OutdoorGame'" ></carouselFixture>
    </acx-scorecard>
</acx-scoreboard>
```

I used the following example:

https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#scorecard

Everything is working fine for me... the issue I am facing. I am trying to implement touch and move functionality for the scorecard. I tried `TouchEvent` but nothing works. Can anyone help me on how to implement touch and move functionality for scorecard?

Comment: Sorry can you add more description on what you are trying to do with touch and move? Are you trying to implement a swipe interface using scorecard? If so scorecard does not support that functionality.

Comment: Actually when I use this scoreboard function it is working perfectly... but when I check it in mobile phone the scoreboard is not scrolling, so I want to implement the touch functionality so that user can touch and move to see all the scorecards.